# Trouble creating AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a first time angularjs user and I am trying to create a directive but I cannot get around this error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- someDirectiveDirective createInjector/providerInjector<@http://localhost:4242/js/lib/angular/angular.js:2734 getService@http://localhost:4242/js/lib/angular/angular.js:2862 createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost:4242/js/lib/angular/angular.js:2739 getService@http://localhost:4242/js/lib/angular/angular.js:2862 ... ... ...
```

I create my angular app as follows:

```
var app = angular.module(
  "myApp", 
  ...
```

I then try and create my directive in another file:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function($http, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
```

Then I use the directive:

I am sure that I am doing something really dumb but I have no idea.

Comment: $scope is not something you can inject into your directive.  (You can inject it into your directive's controller function.)  $element and $attrs can't be injected this way either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yeah guess you can't inject $scope, copied that from one of my services, DOH ;)  Thanks!

Comment: You should explain where the problem is.

Comment: Can you please help me with an example of arbor or something similar in angularjs for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974334/need-hierarchical-tree-visualization-in-angularjs)?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your error is that Angular does not allow you to inject $scope into a directive.

If you want to access $scope from inside a directive then you refer to it as the first argument in the link function (see Epokk's answer).